# show timestamp value while reading hbase table using the HBaseTableCatalog in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to read the hbase table in spark dataframe but not able to get the col timestamp value in resulting dataframe, is there any option need to be set to add timestamp in df.
I am using below code and need timestamp value also the result with column values

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.hbase.{HBaseRelation, HBaseTableCatalog}
val catalog=s"""{
            |"table":{"namespace":"ABC", "name":"Customer"},
            |"rowkey":"key",
            |"columns":{
            |"key":{"cf":"rowkey", "col":"key", "type":"string"},
            |"fld_1":{"cf":"b", "col":"col_1", "type":"string"},
            |"fld_2":{"cf":"b", "col":"col_2", "type":"string"}}}""".stripMargin

val df = withCatalog(groupmember_catalog,sqlContext)
df.show(10, false)
```

Output:

| key | col_1 | col_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -1001010006315999373 | 11649371 | 005100696762 |
| -1001010023217828030 | 11971538 | 192160342 |
| -100101006587656795 | 00365251 | 002975669952 |
| -1001010094594285630 | 59174481 | 006326131142 |
| -1001010105443875786 | 98143111 | 009054316082 |
| -1001010202180534445 | 03070811 | 005369263562 |
| -1001010206526289105 | 59147941 | 007685272362 |
| -100101037570035504 | 00076501 | 000715470712 |
| -1001010392974320818 | 03010961 | 004976432532 |
| -1001010404107816130 | 59592821 | 005479361492 |

Comment: seems like you are using shc connector to read an HBase table into a spark dataframe, unfortunately, the shc connector does not support fetching the timestamp value of HBase cells directly you can instead use other approaches to get timestamp value along with the column values in the resulting dataframe like HBase RDD APIs